# Does Apache Flink support using HTTP requests as input and output?

Tags: apache-flink

As a toy example, say that I would want to build a web application that received HTTP requests with an ID and a $ amount and returned a response with total $ amount that ID has payed over a 24h window. Using Apache Flink it's certainly possible to create that app if the input and output is, say, a Kafka stream.

**But is it supported / possible to create a Flink app where the input is HTTP requests and the output is a response to the HTTP request?**

If this is not supported by Flink, is there another data streaming framework that would support this?

(*For the toy example above, I imagine there are more simple solutions than using Flink, but my real usecase is many, multiple windows and other stateful computations over an HTTP "stream" of requests.*)

Comment: Can You please elaborate why would You like to use such setup? I mean if there are multiple windows and the computation is taking longer time, it seems that requests would have to wait quite a long time.

Comment: So what I would want is a service reachable by an HTTP request that do basically all the things that Flink is doing well: stateful computations and windowed computations. This could, of course, be implemented from scratch, but when I read the Flink documentation there is so much support for the kind of operations I want to have out of the box.

Comment: Yeah, but still it's IMHO questionable whether doing this as a single synchronous request is really a good idea. There various things to consider in such case for example when it comes to timeouts. From Your description it sounds like there is a significant number of operations to be done on the server, so perhaps it would be good to do this asynchronously. 
Finally, Flink offers things like windowing, but so does for example Akka Streams. And honestly if You are not really doing the large scale computations I would perhaps look for some other frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink doesn't provide official HTTP sources or sinks but you could implement your own based on the Sink and Source base classes. However I don't think this is the 'correct' approach, Flink is not designed to receive HTTP requests and answer them directly, Flink normally uses some kind of persistent data source/sinks so it can recreate/recalculate the state if the application fails.

I recommend you use something like Kafka Bridge: https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/07/19/http-bridge-intro/, it allows HTTP clients to write and consume messages from a Kafka topic using simple requests. In this scenario you would have clients posting amount and ID data to a topic, then Flink would use this topic as an input and output results to a second topic. Finally your client can make a second request to poll the results:

client -> KafkaBridge -> InputTopic -> Flink -> ResultsTopic

client -> KafkaBridge -> ResultsTopic

Answer (score 1):

Flink itself doesn't have an HTTP source or sink, but there is a Netty based source in Apache Bahir, which is what You want. You can find more info about `bahir-netty` [here](https://github.com/apache/bahir-flink/tree/master/flink-connector-netty). But as far as I know there is no  Sink that would send data as HTTP requets, so You would probably need to implement that Yourself.

Comment: So, I guess, just a HTTP source and an HTTP sink is not enough. I would need to answer the incoming HTTP request, not just send the result further in another request.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use https://github.com/getindata/flink-http-connector

We have implemented HTTP Sink using Flink's AsyncSink that is available for Streaming and Table API.

As it goes for the source, we have only Lookup Source, that can be used in SQL API for lookup joins.